# Customize SonarQube rules of sonar-web-frontend plugin in sonar dashboard

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, web-frontend, sonarqube-web

I configured sonarQube analyze for my Angular 2 project as this example
[sonar-web-frontend-helloworld](https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-helloworld)

And I added sonar plugin to Jenkins and run gulp task as Jenkins command. It was perfectly worked and now I can view my project in sonar dashboard.

But problem is it uses rules from project not from the sonar server. I have added web-front-end plugin in sonar server. I want to use those set of rules while running code analyzer for my project. And also, using current methods to disable some rules I have to disable them from rules file in the project. How can I improve that sonar job for disable rules using sonar dashboard with log in as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube analysis will always use the rules from the relevant Quality Profile on the server. If you need to adjust the set of rules applied, then you must [edit the profile](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles), most likely the default profile.

Comment: Did you check that example. hear used some set of rules files like .eslintrc, .htmlhintrc ..etc. I think they are control the rules we used. And my sonar job was success fully built.